# how to select option form database with comma between 2 value using php

Tags: php

I have php variable which fetch values from database and php variable is

`$SubTopicid = $L_array["subtopicid"];`

when echo this variable so print a fetching values from database like this

248 72 72,248

issue is that how to option selected with this value `72,248`

I am doing like this way

```
echo '<option value="'.$URow[0].'" '.(($URow[0]==$SubTopicid)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$URow[1].'</option>';
```

It is working ok with this `248 72` but this value `72,248` how to selected in options

Answer (score 0):

If there is any space in your string use this.

```
   echo '<option value="'.$URow[0].'" '.(($URow[0]==$SubTopicid)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'. print(substr("248 72 72,248", 7));.'</option>';
```

else use this

```
echo '<option value="'.$URow[0].'" '.(($URow[0]==$SubTopicid)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'. print(substr("2487272,248",5 ));.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

convert values to string while compare. If I am correct you are not getting select when $SubTopicid value is 72,248. Try below query

```
echo '<option value="'.$URow[0].'" '.(((string)$URow[0]==(string)$SubTopicid)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$URow[1].'</option>';
```

Comment: not working.. issue is that single value is selected because of this "$URow[0]==$SubTopicid" but how to 2 or more than 2 values is selected in option using php

Comment: If you need to select multiple values. Than you can use multiple attribute of html.

Comment: Like 
<select name="sele" multiple><option value="248 72" selected >dasdasd</option><option value="72,248" selected >asdasd</option></select>

Comment: i am fetching values from database

Comment: Yes, I know Just to show I write this htm. Use multipe to select multiple options thats it.